# Selenium: Firefox opens new tab everytime causing the test to fail

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Since I installed Firefox 53, everytime I start one of my automated Selenium tests in Firefox a second tab is opened just a moment after launch, which then prevents my test from finding its needed controls on the first tab and ultimately makes it fail. 
The new tab's url is: https://support.mozilla.org/1/firefox/53.0.2/WINNT/de/insecure-password

The tests work fine in Chrome and Internet Explorer. And there also is no tab opening in when I use Firefox manually. The same problem occurs not only on my local maschine but also on two servers we use as Test Agents for TFS.

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2015 with the packages Selenium.WebDriver and Selenium.Support both in version 3.3, there is a bug that prevents me from using 3.4 (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765261/selenium-remotewebdriver-c-sharp-system-invalidoperationexception)). My Firefox version is 53.0.2, geckodriver is 0.16.1 and Selenium Server Standalone is 3.4.0. I am using the RemoteWebDriver to launch the Browsers.

I've tried finding an about:config value that might disable this new tab or using a custom FirefoxProfile in Selenium, but both to no avail.

Comment: I think if you can downgrade to the stable version 53.0 you can see off the error. But you have to turn-off Private Browsing. Can't comment about  53.0.2. Thanks

Comment: Hi Dev, thanks for your aid. I downgraded to 53 and the error still exists. How do I turn of private browsing?

Comment: Checkout this website: 1. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/955332 Another alternative can be whenever you start your Test, start it in a new Mozilla Firefox profile. Thanks

Comment: The website could not help me, as all the settings mentioned there are already set in my Browser. And as for the custom profile, I already tried that (last paragraph of the question) but could not get it to work, mainly because almost all online examples are in Java and those I found C# contradict each other. So I wasn't able to get it to work.

Comment: Well I code in Java too :) else I would have provided an answer, not a comment. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I downgraded Firefox to 51.0 and it currently works fine as a workaround.