# Getting Timeout exception in Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting session timeout exception in Selenium Grid and then the test case fails.

The error message is as follows

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Session [3d43d8c0-c3e6-482d-9d99-33520fe2a3a4] was terminated due to TIMEOUT
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteNavigator.Refresh()
```

Comment: Could you please give some extra detail?

Comment: @Carlo1585 My test runs through TeamCity, on three different browsers parallelly, But what happens sometimes the selenium shows this error on TeamCity build log, and the test gets fails.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765261/selenium-remotewebdriver-c-sharp-system-invalidoperationexception

Comment: Check you have used long sleep instead of explicit wait

Comment: @Navarasu, I have no where used  long sleep.

Comment: Which line causes this error? Update the question with the error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB,there is no particular line which causes this error.
The stack trace is same in the above question.

Comment: @UjjwalRajShah All of the _Selenium Clients_ are designed to generate helpful error stack trace on exception and without that it's impossible to debug your issue.